# Запрос по нескольким интервалам

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Дана таблица `id | name | datetime`. Существует ли возможность сделать запрос с подсчётом количества `name` по нескольким интервалам времени? Например за сутки с шагом в один час. С 01:00 до 02:00 - 30, с 02:00 до 03:00 - 40 и тд.

Насколько ресурсоёмка данная операция?

Из полученных данных хочу построить график по типу гугл-трендов. Частота упоминания по времени. Если нельзя сделать такой запрос, то как можно реализовать подобное?

Comment: 24 case решают проблему: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement.html

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko у индусов учились?

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko Спасибо, хороший сайт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение вашей задачи. Скорое всего, этот запрос можно и нужно оптимизировать:

```
SELECT HOUR(DataAndTime), COUNT(*) 
FROM log 
WHERE DataAndTime BETWEEN '2017-07-25 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-25 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY hour(DataAndTime)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Ларец просто открывался, оказывается. А я уже на полстраницы SELECT'ов понаписал для получения этого же результата)))